# SonarQube Analysis / Results / Issues by Team or Group

Tags: sonarqube, rtc, ibm-jazz

Running SonarQube 5.6.7 and need to know if SonarQube can be configured to provide analysis of activity and issues by Team or Group, in addition to the already existing filter by Author

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the [`sonar-scm-jazzrtc`](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-scm-jazzrtc) source code suggests it can focus on activities (change sets) (by group/Team or not)

The plugin is just here to checkout the code (from the current stream) in a local workspace, in order for the Sonarqube scanner to scan.